# Java hibernate: Update foreign key in manytoone relationship automatically

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have a problem with the auto update of foreign keys which appears as following:

I have a two tables HamKeyword and HamKeywordAlias.  One entry in the hamKeyword has 0…n entries in HamKeywordAlias. This relationship is reflected with a foreign key field in the  HamKeywordAlias table. Both tables have their own primary keys. I defined the two tables using reverse engineering of hibernate eclipse tools as follows:

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "HAM_KEYWORDS")
    public class HamKeywords implements java.io.Serializable {

        private long keywordid;
        private String keyword;
    …
        @Id
        @GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "KEYWORDID", unique = true)
        public long getKeywordid() {
            return this.keywordid;
        }
    …
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "hamKeywords")
        public Set<HamKeywordsAlias> getHamKeywordsAliases() {
            return this.hamKeywordsAliases;
        }


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "HAM_KEYWORDS_ALIAS", schema = "dbo", catalog = "ham")
    public class HamKeywordsAlias implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
        @GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
        @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
        @Column(name = "ALIASID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public long getAliasid() {
            return this.aliasid;
        }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "KEYWORDID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
        public HamKeywords getHamKeywords() {
            return this.hamKeywords;
        }
```

Now to my problem. I try to add a new entry to HamKeyword with 1 new related HamKeywordAlias:

```
HamKeywords hkw = new HamKeywords();
HamKeywordsAlias hka = new HamKeywordsAlias();
hka.setAlias("new alias");
hkw.setHamKeywordsAliases(new HashSet<HamKeywordsAlias>());
Set<HamKeywordsAlias> hkaS = hkw.getHamKeywordsAliases();
hkaS.add(hka);
hkw.setHamKeywordsAliases(hkaS);
session.flush();
session.save(hkw);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

This code fails with the error message:

```
ERROR: The value NULL can not be inserted in table 'KEYWORDID'-Spalte, 'ham.dbo.HAM_KEYWORDS'. No NULL allowed for INSERT. Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

(Please note that I translated the error message into english, it might be a bit different languagewise)

Obviously, the foreign key in field KEYWORDID of the HamKeywordAlias table is not be updated. I double checked this by removing the NOT NULL constraint. What happens is, that the enty into the ALIAS table is inserted but with a NULL in the field keywordid.

I tested furthermore adding manually rows into the HamKeywordAlias table. Retrieving an entry of the HamKeyword table and retrieving the related Aliases with following code works great:

```
HamKeywords hamCurrentKeyword = (HamKeywords) session.get(HamKeywords.class, (long)1);
hamCurrentKeyword.getHamKeywordsAliases();
```

Thus I assume that I defined the many to one relation correctly. However, the foreign key is not updated automatically.
Can you assist me why this is not be done?

Thanks

Felix

Answer (score 0):

You have a bidirectional OneToMany association. The owner of the association is the Many side: `HamKeywordsAlias.hamKeywords`. That's the side that Hibernate cares about. But you didn't initialize it. You added an alias to the keywords' collection of aliases, but failed to set the keywords of the alias:

```
hka.setHamKeywords(hkw);
```